# Is read_ods reading one more row than required?

Tags: r

I'm using read_ods() from the readODS package for getting a table from a LibreOffice spreadsheet into r. It works but it seems to read one more row than expected:

```
    > read_ods(data_dir %+% "OpenDocument Spreadsheet.ods", sheet = "Sheet1", range = "A1:B4")
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  A = col_character(),
  B = col_character()
)
          A         B
1         1         4
2         2         5
3         3         6
4 DoNotRead DoNotRead
```

The table has 4 rows including titles, but read_ods gets 5 rows (1 titles row + 4). If I set the range argument with one less row (which is wrong) I get the expected result:

```
> read_ods(data_dir %+% "OpenDocument Spreadsheet.ods", sheet = "Sheet1", range = "A1:B3")
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  A = col_character(),
  B = col_character()
)
  A B
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks,

P.D.: I didn't manage a way to upload the file for making a perfect reproductible example, buy any table would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted the developers in GitHub and reported the issue some days ago. Turns out it is a bug. I undestand that it will be fixed with following releases (v1.7).